# Number of distinct red and blue colored cycles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider a cycle graph of length $n$ where $k$ nodes are colored blue and $n-k$ are colored red. I define two vectors $x,y$ each of length $l$ where $l$ is the number of connected components of red and blue colored subgraphs and the entries in the vectors are defined by the size of said subgraphs. $x$ and $y$ always have to be of the same length $l$ since the coloring alternates between blue and red colored sub-graphs.

I want to find the number of distinct configurations and, hence, I have to get rid of those who I count twice due to symmetries implied by the symmetric group $S_l$ on the vectors $l$.

To rewrite this I consider two vectors of positive integers which I call obviously $x,y$ such that the length of $x$ is $l$ and the length of $y$ is likewise $l$ with $x_i\in\{1,...,k\}$ and $y_i\in\{1,...,n-k\}$ for $i=1,...,l$ and $\sum_{i=1}^l x_i = k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^l y_i = n-k$ for some positive integer $n>k$. Then two configurations are identical under a rotation of $2\pi \dfrac{r}{n}$ iff $x_i = x_{(i+r)\mathrm{mod}\;l}$ and $y_i = y_{(i+r)\mathrm{mod}\;l}$ since both $x$ and $y$ have to be rotated. Note that if you find such an $r$ for a pair $x,y$ it is not true that the same $r$ is preserved under arbitrary actions of $S_l$ on $x$ and $y$.

Can these numbers be counted or is there no hope to even get a recursive formula for the number of "identical" $x$ ad $y$ which can be rotated in this way?

Comment: Do you mean that $x_iy_i=0$ for every $i=1,\dots, l$?

Comment: No, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are always positive. I changed the question to clear up their definition.

Comment: I overlooked that the number of red components must be the same as the number of blue components. Maybe you should emphasize it a bit more! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) to solve the problem for any particular $n,k,l$. I haven't been able to extract a formula for the general solution.

Think of the sequences $x$ and $y$ as "coloring" the set $\{1,2,\dots,l\}$ by giving element $i$ the "color" $(x_i, y_i)$. If we give color $(x_i, y_i)$ weight $(x_i, y_i)$ as well, then the condition that $\sum_{i=1}^l x_i = k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^l y_i = n-k$ tells us that the total weight of the coloring must be (k,n-k)$.

In the notation of the Wikipedia article, the color generating function is
$$
   f(t_1, t_2) = \frac{t_1 t_2}{(1 - t_1)(1-t_2)}
$$
in which the coefficient of $t_1^i t_2^j$ is $1$ for all $i,j\ge 1$, corresponding to how there's a single color of each weight that's positive in both coordinates.

The cycle index $Z_G(t_1, \dots, t_l)$ is a generating function for the cycle structures of the elements of the group $G$, which in this case is the $l$-element cyclic group. This is what's going to give us the most trouble. When $l$ is prime, we have $l-1$ elements which are $l$-cycles (as permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,l\}$) and one identity element, so in that case
$$
   Z_G(t_1, \dots, t_l) = \frac{t_1^l + (l-1) t_l}{l}.
$$
When $l$ is not prime, things get trickier. For example, when $l=6$, the identity still has term $t_1^6$ and rotations by $\frac\pi3$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ still have term $t_6$, but rotations by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ have term $t_3^2$ (two $3$-cycles) and rotating by $\pi$ has term $t_2^3$ (three $2$-cycles) so we get
$$
   Z_G(t_1, \dots, t_6) = \frac{t_1^6 + t_2^3 + 2t_3^2 + 2t_6}{6}.
$$
In general, if $\phi$ is the totient function, we have
$$
   Z_G(t_1, \dots, t_l) = \frac1l \sum_{d \mid l} \phi(d) t_{d}^{l/d}.
$$
Then the number of solutions is the coefficient of $t_1^k t_2^{n-k}$ in
$$
  Z_G(f(t_1, t_2), f(t_1^2, t_2^2), \dots, f(t_1^l, t_2^l)) = \frac{(t_1 t_2)^l}{l} \sum_{d \mid l} \frac{\phi(d)}{((1-t_1^d)(1-t_2^d))^{l/d}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the great response!! How did you derive $f(t_1,t_2)$?

Comment: $f(t_1, t_2) = \sum_{i \ge 1} \sum_{j \ge 1} t_1^i t_2^j$ and then we get the rational function by the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: Ok, I did not get from the Wikipedia article how $f(t_1,t_2,..)$ is defined. Thanks!

Comment: Now your answer gives me the number of orbits of the colored set $\{1,...,l\}$. Can I also say something about the sum of the size  of the distinct orbits? by classical group theory for orbits $O_G$ of some set $X$ under the group action $G$ we have $\sum_{O_G}|O_G|=|X|$. Therefore, we have in this case $\sum_{O_G}|O_G|=|Y^{\{1,...,l\}}|$ using the Wikipedia notations. But now can I express $|Y^{\{1,...,l\}}|$ in some closed form?

Comment: $|Y^{\{1,...,l\}}|$ is just the number of ways to pick $x$ and $y$ without regard to symmetry. There are $\binom{k+l-1}{l-1}$ ways to partition $k$ into a sum of $l$ terms, and $\binom{n-k+l-1}{l-1}$ ways to do the same for $n-k$, so $|Y^{\{1,...,l\}}| = \binom{k+k-1}{k-1} \binom{n+k+l-1}{l-1}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If $n$ is even and I pick $k =\frac{n}{2}$ as well as $l=\frac{n}{2}$ then there are exactly two ways to color the necklace $\{1,2,3,4,...,n\}$, either $\{2,4,6,...,n\}$ blue and $\{1,3,5,...,n-1\}$ red or inversely, where they can be obtained by a simple rotation. So the number of distinct nacklaces is one and the number of colorings is 2 but when using your formula for $|Y^{\{1,...,l\}}|$ I obtain 1225. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: I think I forgot to use the formula for sums of **positive** terms rather than for **nonnegative** terms. There are only $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ ways to partition $n$ into a sum of $r$ positive terms, giving us $\binom{k-1}{\ell-1}\binom{n-k-1}{\ell-1}$, and that's $1$ in your example.

Comment: Thanks, if I multiply $\binom{k-1}{l-1}\binom{n-k}{l-1}$ with $\frac{n}{l}$ I obtain the correct solution when comparing with cases I can solve with a computer. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Is there a combinatorial interpretation for the term $\binom{k-1}{l-1}\binom{n-k}{l-1}\frac{n}{l}$?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious; I'm especially confused by the difference between $\binom{n-k}{l-1}$ and $\binom{n-k-1}{l-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo due to copy paste! It's $\binom{k-1}{l-1}\binom{n-k-1}{l-1}\frac{n}{l}$.

Comment: I am going to open another question. Thanks a lot for all your help.